# Spring boot app can't conncect to mysql server on local network

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

For some reason my app can't connect to mysql server on local network. The thing is that I CAN connect to it from my datasource browser (Intellij) using SAME credentials and SAME url. Previously everything was working fine when i ran the SAME code on my desktop. The only thing that changed for me is that i got myself new laptop for work. For some reason when spring boot is loading it hangs on Hikari Pool connection for about 30 seconds and throws connection timeout exception afterwards.

My network setup:

- my linux (Mint) laptop that runs the code (192.168.1.4)
- old server laptop on linux (CentOS) with mysql (192.168.1.5)

all IPs are fixed

mysql creds:

- db name (dnd_service)
- db pass (12345678)
- user (dnd-service)
- user pass (12345678)

i CAN ping my server:

```
PING 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.32 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=9.01 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=8.31 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=12.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.5: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=97.3 ms
```

3306 port is OPEN and Accessible (I check with telnet):

```
telnet 192.168.1.5 3306
Trying 192.168.1.5...
Connected to 192.168.1.5.
Escape character is '^]'.
J
v�vV[wJ!`caching_sha2_password
```

I CAN connect to mysql with intellij:
[image]

my application.properties:

```
server.port=8090
server.servlet.context-path=/

spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/dnd_service?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=dnd-service
spring.datasource.password=12345678

spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL
```

whe I try to run my app I get the following output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.2.RELEASE)

2021-02-03 14:26:34,815 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger: Starting Application.Companion on cvazer-laptop with PID 24924 (/home/cvazer/Programming/remote/dnd-service/build/classes/kotlin/main started by cvazer in /home/cvazer/Programming/remote/dnd-service)
2021-02-03 14:26:34,820 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-03 14:26:35,960 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate: Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2021-02-03 14:26:36,243 INFO  [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate: Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 269ms. Found 44 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-02-03 14:26:37,007 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-02-03 14:26:37,021 INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2021-02-03 14:26:37,022 INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-02-03 14:26:37,023 INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2021-02-03 14:26:37,115 INFO  [main] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-02-03 14:26:37,115 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2022 ms
2021-02-03 14:26:37,374 INFO  [main] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport: Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-02-03 14:26:37,442 INFO  [task-1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-02-03 14:26:37,515 INFO  [task-1] org.hibernate.Version: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.18.Final
2021-02-03 14:26:37,742 INFO  [task-1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2021-02-03 14:26:37,897 INFO  [task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-02-03 14:27:09,048 ERROR [task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60251', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Last exception is

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

As I understand it, everything SHOULD work but for some reason it doesn't and I don't know why

Just in case my build script:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.72'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.3.72'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa' version '1.3.72'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen' version '1.3.72'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version '1.3.72'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group 'com.gitlab.cvazer'
version '1.0.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

allOpen {
    annotation('javax.persistence.Entity')
    annotation('javax.persistence.Embeddable')
    annotation('javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.23'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:2.2.3'
    implementation 'com.javaetmoi.core:javaetmoi-hibernate5-hydrate:5.2.2'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-jsr223:3.0.5'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:3.0.5'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

Comment: Disable firewall.

Comment: I already disabled it on bouth laptops

Comment: The server needs some configuration, and Mysql users must allowed to access server from network. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Answer (score 1):

can you replace your spring.datasource.url with
`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dnd_service?user=dnd-service&12345678&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Comment: No luck =( I tried both `localhost` and `192.168.1.5` in your url, same exception